# MYSQL group products by compatibilty

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, group-concat

I have two tables, one is for kits that can contain various sub-products, and another is a list of sub-products that can't be added together in the same kit.

In simplified form:

```
CREATE TABLE `kits` (
    `subProdID` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `kitID` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `kitName` VARCHAR(512) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`subProdID`)
);

CREATE TABLE `subProd_incompatible` (
    `IncompID` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `subProdID` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `subProdIncompID` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`VersaIncompID`)
)
```

In `subProd_incompatible`, `subProdID` and `subProdIncompID` all exist as subProdIDs in `kits`.

Right now I use procedural code outside the database to produce a list of kits that all contain products that do not conflict according to the `subProd_incompatible` table, but I'd like to do it in SQL if at all possible.

What I'd like is to

```
SELECT `kitID`, `kitName`, GROUP_CONCAT(`subProdID`)
FROM ("a subquery") AS Q
GROUP BY `GroupingCriterion`
```

"a subquery" should return the columns of `kits`, along with a generated `GroupingCriterion`.

Comment: Can you some sample data and desired o/p?

Comment: Your data structure doesn't really make sense, unless a subproduct can only be in one kit.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: a subproduct can be in more than one kit. Also the real data I'm working with is much wider, this is just a pared down, anonimized version of it. Also note that not every subproduct in the `kita` table has an incompatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea.  For each kit, get the list of the matches to the incompatible table for each subproduct.  Then, aggregate by the kit *and* incompatible id and see if any have two products.  If so, you have incompatible products in the kit:

```
select k.kitid, i.InCompId
from kits k join
     subProd_incompatible i
     on k.subProdId in (i.subProdId, i.subProdIncompID)
group by k.kitid, i.InCompId
having count(distinct k.subProdId) = 2;
```

Comment: Okay, that's getting closer. What I'm ultimately working towards is a column in the returned subquery that identifies groups of subproducts that are all compatible with each other.

Comment: @FenugreekFemtosecond . . . That doesn't sound like the question you asked.  I would suggest that you ask another question along with sample data and desired results.  Changing a question to invalidate an answer is not only impolite (it draws downvotes) but it also might make others reluctant to answer the question.